# How to prove $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim p_g}[f(X)] = \mathbb{E}_{Z \sim p_z}[f(G(Z))]$ where $G(Z) \sim p_g$

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

How do I  prove $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim p_g}[f(X)] = \mathbb{E}_{Z \sim p_z}[f(G(Z))]$ where $G(Z) \sim p_g$ **without necessarily assuming** $G$ is monotonic? I think this is intuitively very clear but without using the formula
$$
p_g(x) = p_z(G^{-1}(x)) (dz/dx),
$$
the problem seems not trivial.

After spending some time pondering on it, it makes me think that maybe this is the only way to prove it.

So, to prove the above, do I need to resort to the 'local' argument, using inverse function theorem?

Comment: But it **is** trivial: you know that $X$ and $G(Z)$ have the same distribution hence $E(f(X))=E(f(G(Z)))$ for every measurable $f$ such that the expectations exist. No idea about what you are trying to do with inverse functions here.

Comment: @Did Yes, but you also know that the precise integral definitions are different. If we start there, we cannot immediately conclude this, or can we..?

Comment: "you also know that the precise integral definitions are different." Sorry but no, I do not "know that". What are you talking about?

Comment: The integral definition of $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ and that of $\mathbb{E}[f(G(Z))]$. They are different in terms of notations.

Comment: If you turn to what these notations mean, in both cases, you arrive at $$\int f(x)dp_g(x)$$ since $p_g$ is the distribution of $X$ and also the distribution of $G(Z)$.